# Creating new column that flags row based on conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to filter this dataframe called `df`

```
structure(list(ï..ID = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 
8L), .Label = c("Jay ", "Jim", "Jim ", "John ", "Mike ", "Peter", 
"Peter ", "Tom"), class = "factor"), Target1 = structure(c(8L, 
4L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 7L), .Label = c("Andreas", "Cheyne", 
"Frank", "John", "Mickey", "Raj", "Sarah", "Timothy"), class = "factor"), 
    Target2 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Jake", "Peter", "Timothy ", "Tommy "), class = "factor"), 
    Parter1 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "Mike ", "Timothy"), class = "factor"), Parter2 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "Peter"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I'm trying to filter the dataframe such that if the names that appear in this vector `x`

```
x=c("Raj", "Timothy")
```

appears more than 2 times in columns 2-5 the row will have a variable for a brand new column called `flag` where flag =1 if the name appears more than 2 times and flag=0 if the name does not appear more than 2 times.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, you want the new column to `=1` if either Raj and/or Timothy appear twice across the other columns in that row, or zero otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Base R, we could use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` (row-wise)

```
df$flag <- as.integer(apply(df, 1, function(row) sum(row %in% x)) > 2)

df
#  ï..ID Target1 Target2 Parter1 Parter2 flag
#1   Jim Timothy Timothy Timothy            1
#2   Jay    John   Peter    Mike   Peter    0
#3  John     Raj                            0
#4 Peter  Mickey   Tommy                    0
#5   Jim  Cheyne    Jake                    0
#6 Peter Andreas                            0
#7  Mike   Frank                            0
#8   Tom   Sarah                            0
```

---

`apply` converts dataframe to matrix and can be slow some time. You can avoid `apply` call using `sapply` with same logic

```
df$flag <- as.integer(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) sum(df[i, ] %in% x)) > 2)
```

And another way to write it

```
df$flag <- as.integer(colSums(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df[i, ] %in% x)) > 2)
```

PS - You had some white-spaces in the names, I had to first run

```
df[] <- lapply(df, trimws)
```

to remove them.

Comment: Works great! 1 question how would I add something about whether I wanted an & condition in the code? Like if I wanted it to flag based on whether there were 2 in that list & whether there were multiple empty spaces like ''

Comment: @M76 Let's say you want to check whether there are more than 1 empty spaces in every row you can add an additional `&` condition like `df$flag <- as.integer(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) sum(df[i, ] %in% x) > 2 & sum(df[i, ] == "") > 1))`